# Build error in Jasmine.d.ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine

I am getting following build error after adding jasmine.d.ts file. I have verified that there is no duplicate entry exist. Also, this definition file has not been referenced anywhere in my project.

[image: build error]

I have searched a lot but did not find any way out. Is this an issue in the file?

Comment: It can be implicitly reference if something else (that is included) references it.

Comment: @sachin-gaur where exactly did you add `jasmine.d.ts`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Angular too? You might have the "Angular Scenario Testing" definition file because it also contains the describe/xdescribe and after/before-each functions.

I think that might be the reason are popping up after adding jasmine.d.ts.